# How can I call the ViewDidAppear only one time?

Tags: iphone, sdk, xib, viewdidappear

When the user start the app I want it show the stockholm.xib
and It does here:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *startPage =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *page =[startPage stringForKey:@"page"];
    NSLog(page);

    if(page==nil)
    {
        //Do nothing

    }
    else if ([page isEqualToString:@"Default"])
    {
        //Do nothing
    }

    else if ([page isEqualToString:@"Stockholm"])
    {
        NSLog(@"going to Stockholm");
        Stockholm *Start =[[Stockholm alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:Start animated:YES];


    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"HAHA");

}
```

but when user closes the stockholm.xib using:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

after the animation is done, the app crashes. 
and the reason is, I guess, viewDidAppear calls twice and therefore it is trying to open the recently closed xib file.

now, how Can I call the view did appear only once? so that when the user comes back from Stockholm the viewDidAppear wont be called? any other solution?

thanx :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try moving all that functionality in the `viewDidLoad:` method instead of the `viewDidAppear`. That one only fires once. Unless there is a reason for you not to...?

EDIT: more code to show what i mean in the comment

in the .h file:

```
BOOL firstTime;
```

in the .m file:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   NSLog(@"viewDidLoad actually fired");
   //...
   firstTime = YES;
}
-(void)viewDidAppear {
   //...
   if(firstTime){
      //show it
      firstTime = NO;
   }
}
```

Comment: yes, the reason is that If I move this:

 Stockholm *Start =[[Stockholm alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 [self presentModalViewController:Start animated:YES];

to viewdidLoad, it wont work.

Comment: If you only want to show it the first time the view appears, just use a boolean flag to tell if it is the first time or not. BOOL firstTime = true; if(... && firstTime) { firstTime = false; ...}

Comment: It still doesnt work. 

.h
static BOOL firstTime=TRUE;

.m
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];
 if (firstTime=TRUE) {
  //Go to the custom Page
 }
 firstTime=FALSE;
}

i get this error:
0x018ce464  <+0665>  jne    0x18ce481 <-[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:]+694>


please HELP!

Answer (score 6):

You can use GCD, too, if your class has a field such as:

```
@interface MyClass {
    dispatch_once_t once;
}

@end

@interface MyClass {
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        dispatch_once(&once, ^{
            // do business
        });
    }
@end
```

Comment: EDIT: Still need the flag.  Using a method static would mean the code would run just once no matter how many instances of the view controller were created.

Comment: This is _seems_ like a good idea, but it will actually result in undefined behavior: `The predicate must point to a variable stored in global or static scope. The result of using a predicate with automatic or dynamic storage is undefined.`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the property like BOOL loaded to your viewcontroller, set it to false in the viewdidload, and then make your viewDidAppear method like:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (!loaded) {
        //code
    } else {
        return;
    }
    loaded = YES;
}
```

That works for me.